# Visual Studio unable to open HTML file for edit but open with Chrome instead

Tags: visual-studio

I just recently installed Visual Studio Community 2017 (with just the **ASP.NET and Web Development** module selected). All the while with VS2015, after opening my solution file, I just need to double-click any HTML file from the Solution Explorer and I'll be able to edit it within the IDE itself **(without having to associate my HTML file type with VS)**, but now, each time I double-click the HTML file, it opens it on Chrome by default (and with the "Access denied" error message) -- I want to know what's wrong? Now I can't edit my HTML at all with VS Community 2017, need help. Thanks in advance!

*P/S: I do not want to change my HTML association. I still prefer it to be opened on Google Chrome from the **File Explorer** except while in VS2017 IDE. Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved by:

1. Removing an **unknown user**, who could be the owner of the folder that holds the HTML files. This "unknown user" could be myself in my old PC as I copied the files and folders from my old hard drive to the current PC.
2. Replace the child object permission entries with the inheritable
   permission entries from the project folder.

This problem could happen when you transfer your old code files and folders from old PC to new PC.